# How to register In-band user in particular Virtual Host in Ejabberd with Smack Client?

Tags: ejabberd, smack, ejabberd-api

I am using Smack client 4.3.1 and want to register user using in-band registration method (using Smack's AccountManager).

I could create new user with "admin" XMPP connection and users are created in a domain where admin user is there  say user1@ec2-xxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

My requirement is, i want to create user in another virtual host - say user1@example.com using same "admin" XMPP connection.  is it possible ?

I tried "in band registration" with user "mnallath1@example.com" which has admin privilege.  it is giving "XMPPError: conflict - cancel " error

My code is :

```
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection1);
    System.out.println("Is Account creation supported " +accountManager.isSupported() + " Account creation supported : " + accountManager.supportsAccountCreation());
    accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);

    EntityFullJid entityFullJid = JidCreate.entityFullFrom("user1@example.com/resource1");

    Domainpart domainpart = entityFullJid.getDomain();

    Localpart localpart = entityFullJid.getLocalpart();

    System.out.println("local part of account " + localpart);

    accountManager.createAccount(localpart, "password");
```

is it possible to create user1 in example.com using in-band registration ?

my admin users

```
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin": "ec2-xxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
      - "mnallath1": "example.com"
```

my virtual hosts

```
hosts:
  - "ec2-xxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
  - "example.com"
  - "example.net"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it is now allowed to register new accounts using IBR from another vhost, even if done using an admin account.

The function check_from returns deny because the account used does not belong to the vhost where the registration is attempted:
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_register.erl#L260